# Programmatically creating posts based on external JSON feed (asynchronously)

Tags: plugin-development, database, api, json, import

I am currently trying to create a Wordpress plugin which create posts in the Wordpress database based on data from an external JSON API. As an example this NewsAPI feed could be used:

https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?sources=techcrunch&apiKey=81143272da6c48d58bc38fe80dd110d6

The plugin I have written decodes the JSON data by using `json_decode` and loops through the `article` object in the JSON feed. Finally, the posts is being inserted programmatically using `wp_insert_post`:

```
<?php

/**
* Plugin Name: Automatic News Feed Importer
* Version: 1.0.0
*/

function news_importer() {
$url = "https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?sources=techcrunch&apiKey=81143272da6c48d58bc38fe80dd110d6";
$response = wp_remote_get( $url );
$data = json_decode( wp_remote_retrieve_body( $response ) );

foreach( $data->articles as $news ) {
    $post_title = $news->title;
    $post_content = $news->content;
    $post_date = $news->publishedAt;
    
    $post = array(
        'post_title' => $post_title,
        'post_content' => $post_content,
        'post_date' => $post_date,
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'post_type' => 'post'
    );
    
    wp_insert_post( $post );

    }
}
```

My problem is that when the plugin is activated, no posts are creating and added to the database. When a new post is uploaded and appearing in the feed it has to be uploaded automatically (asynchronously).

Any ideas on why this isn't working?

Comment: Are you *sure* you're getting data back from the server? I tried your URL and got an error. (Also, if that's your personal API key, you'll probably want to get it changed, since these questions are publicly visible.)

Comment: How are you calling `news_importer()`?  You've defined it in your plugin, where are calling it from?

Comment: I agree with @Pat and @darrinb. Are you sure the API actually returned a valid data containing the `articles` array - have you confirmed `$data->articles` is set, and that `news_importer()` and `wp_insert_post()` were both called? Also, you could try setting the 2nd parameter to true (e.g. `$post_id = wp_insert_post( $post, true );`), and check if an error is returned - see example [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_insert_post/#comment-2096).

Answer (score 0):

By checking if the 'products' object exists in an `if` statement and looping through the objects (as in the code above), the function seems to be working:

```
function json_to_post() {
  $response = wp_remote_get('https://dummyjson.com/products');
  $json_data = wp_remote_retrieve_body($response);
  $data = json_decode($json_data, true);

  if (isset($data['products'])) {
  $products = $data['products'];
  foreach ($products as $post) {
    $title = $post['title'];
    $content = $post['description'];

    $new_post = array(
      'post_title' => $title,
      'post_content' => $content,
      'post_status' => 'publish',
      'post_type' => 'post'
  );
    wp_insert_post($new_post);
  }
 }
}
add_action('init', 'json_to_post');
```

Comment: Can you instead add this as an additional info in your post/question? And add other details like, 1) How and when do you call `news_importer()` - have you confirmed the function is actually being called? 2) What exactly is the error the API in question returned? 3) Have you tried setting the `$wp_error` parameter to true - see my comment on your question. As for your code in this answer, though, if `news_importer` did run, then the problem was likely that `post_category` must be an [**array** of category IDs](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_insert_post/#parameters).

Comment: Hi Sally. Thank you very much for your feedback. By using your suggestions, I have managed to come up with a solution which seems to be working. Kindly see the edited answer above.

Comment: Yes, that looks fine now, but you could do `if ( ! is_array( $data ) || empty( $data['products'] ) ) { return; } foreach ...` instead of `if ( isset( $data['products'] ) ) { foreach ... }`. However, this answer didn't answer your question.. But validating a data and checking for errors is always good, e.g. don't simply access the `products` without first validating it's set. Also, be sure to check the arguments accepted by `wp_insert_post()`, e.g. supply an array if the argument expects an array. And lastly, I assumed `init` was used just for testing...

Answer (score 0):

There's a ready built plugin that does exactly this:

https://wpgetapi.com/downloads/custom-post-import/